# AJAX chat commands - if command doesn't exist, echo error

Tags: php, function, oop

So I have this commands handling:

$message = the entered message.

```
    public function handleCommands($message, $username)
    {
        //Variables we're going to use
        $space = strpos($message, ' '); # The first space.
        $command = trim(substr($message, 1, $space)); # The command after the slash
        $name = substr($message, $space + 1); # The name after the command.


        switch ($command)
        {
            case 'ban':
                $this->ban($name, $username);
            break;

            case 'prune':
                $this->prune($username);
            break;

            case '':
                echo 'Please use a command!';
            break;

            case 'test':
                try
                {
                    $this->test($name);
                }
                catch (exception $r)
                {
                    echo $r->getMessage();
                }
            break;
        }
    }
```

This basically will check for the command.

$command = the entered word after the slash ( " / " ).

Can you see

```
case '':
```

This basically checks if there is no command after the slash.

***Question:*** I want the system to check aswell, if the command exists in the cases.

For example:

user wrote:

/hello

But that command doesn't exists, considering we only have case 'ban', case 'prune', case 'test' and case ''.

there is no case 'hello', so it will throw an error.
Is there a function that does this sort of thing? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a `default:` case.

**Example:**

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i equals 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "i equals 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "i equals 2";
        break;
    default:
       echo "i is not equal to 0, 1 or 2";
}
?>
```

**EDIT**:
Fixed version of problem that was chatted about: http://privatepaste.com/bd34e7e63b

Comment: For some reason, when I write /blablabla in my chat, it activates the case " case '': ", but when I add a space like: "/blablabla " it works. Any idea why?

Comment: `trim(substr($message, 1, $space));` is erasing the entire variable. Replace it with `$command = substr(strrchr($message, '/'), 1);` and you should get what you want. Providing that you're just looking for the data sans '/'.

Comment: Oh great man! So many functions I didn't use, I am definitely going to look after them now.

Comment: Not solved, I now can't use a command like /ban playername. It says doesn't exist

Comment: Pastebin the code you're using. It should work. My test is here: http://privatepaste.com/afc242ad28 and the case was recognized successfully.

Comment: If your input was "/ban" like mine is, our result(s) should be congruent. What was your input?

Comment: My input was /ban jony, as I said, it doesn't support a name. thats why it was trim(substr($message, 1, $space))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32103/discussion-between-jony-kale-and-justice-cassel)

Answer (score 1):

Use the case default:

```
    switch ($command)
    {
        case 'ban':
            $this->ban($name, $username);
        break;

        case 'prune':
            $this->prune($username);
        break;

        case '':
            echo 'Please use a command!';
        break;

        case 'test':
            try
            {
                $this->test($name);
            }
            catch (exception $r)
            {
                echo $r->getMessage();
            }
        break;

        default:
            echo "That command does not exist.";
    }
```